Merging layers? objects? in the Outliners
I drew an outline of a head in Grease Pencil. I mistakenly used two different Grease Pencil layers? objects? in the Outliner under Collection. How do I merge them into one layer under the Head Outline group? I have tried copy and pasting, clicking and dragging, and nothing works. I eventually want to join it all together as one object.

